# Customizing the display of Recent Contributions on Contribution > Dashboard

Tags: contributions, dashboard

I would like to be able to display a contributors assigned/chosen Campaign on the Recent Contributions dashboard:

[image: Contribution - Recent Dashboard]

Any way to customize these dashboards?

Thanks,

E